# Mouse pointer does not show on mouse entering/hovering/focus over hyper-v guest OS window

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, mouse, hyper-v, centos-7

I'm running Hyper-V on a Windows 10 1703 system.  My Virtual Machine guest operating system is CentOS 7.2 and is generation 2.  I have integrated services installed (see image below).  I have a four monitor setup with my Windows 10.  I have my VM open on Monitor 1 in a window (not full screen).  On Monitor 2 I have Chrome running on the Windows 10 system.

When I move my mouse off Chrome (or any other program on that screen for that matter) and over the VM, my mouse pointer disappears.  I have to click on the virtual machine window to see the pointer.

The problem is that click to get the mouse to show also is registered by the virtual machine.  Thus, depending on where on the screen that click happens, the click can sometimes shutdown a process I am in the middle of or close a terminal window or open a program... you get the picture; I never know where/what I am clicking on to enter the VM.

I don't care that I have to click to start using the VM.  I do care that I can't see what is being clicked.

Since my Integrated Services are installed I'm really at a loss as to what is causing this and how to proceed with troubleshooting/fixing.

Can anyone provide a solution or point me in a direction to start troubleshooting this?

[image: Screenshot showing VM Integrated Services]

Comment: Are you sure you have the integration services installed on the VM properly? What process did you use?

Comment: My understanding is these are built in to the kernel since CentOS 6.4 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/supported-centos-and-red-hat-enterprise-linux-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v